# The entries of a random matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, matlab

I am confused about something. Whenever I create an $n\times n$ random matrix using Matlab (using the command $A=\mathrm{rand}(n,n)$), I get a square matrix whose entries are all between $0$ and $1$.

Are the entries of a random matrix allowed to be equal to $0$ or $1$?

Comment: yes, but it will happen with probability $0$.

Comment: @Denis: Does that mean that no entry can be equal to $0$ or $1$ ?

Comment: Since computer arithmetic is finite, it will happen with positive probability, but only a **very** small one.

Comment: the coefficients you actually got had the same probability to come up (zero if they were purely mathematical, very small in a real-world computer).

Comment: @M.Krov but to answer your question, if the Matlab algorithm is reasonable, it won't happen in your lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html), it clearly states that the rand function gives entries drawn from the standard uniform distribution on the **open** interval $(0,1)$. Thus, you will never get $0$ or $1$. Even if the endpoints were included, the probability of getting $0$ or $1$ would be effectively zero.

Comment: The probability that `rand` returns a specific number is very small but not zero, because of finite precision with floating numbers